# Is there a limit for the amount of items with some content type in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, rest, content-type

I'm having a problem getting all the items related to certain **Content Type** through REST API from a document library, I did a test reducing the amount of documents under that Content Type and the app started to show the items, so I wonder if is there a restriction or limit in the amount of files or items that I can get and how can I fix it

The endpoint I'm using is this:

```
var url = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$select=FileRef,ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl,Title,URL,File&$expand=File&$filter=ContentType eq '" + cttypeName + "'";
```

Comment: Yes it is limited to 100 items. Use paging. use the search bar at the top of the page and search for REST API paging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API by default only returns 100 items so the way I could get more was using **$top=number_of_items** in the REST Endpoint.

```
var url = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$top=1000&$select=FileRef,File&$expand=File&$filter=ContentType eq '" + cttypeName + "'";
```